# How do I turn an image into a link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to do a simple link on an image.

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="path/to/image.png"/></a>
```

How do you do this with a link_to rails tag?

Answer (score 79):

Use an `image_tag` for the contents of the `link_to`.

```
link_to image_tag("path/to/image.png"), "http://www.mysite.com/"
```

Comment: thanks It worked. I forgot to ask how you add a class or id to the image?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. link_to image_tag("path/to/image.png", :class => "class_name"), "http://www.google.com/"

Answer (score 30):

my solution:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
   <%= image_tag "image.jpg", class: "some css class here" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This answer worked better for me because I didn't have to mess with the syntax of my image_tag to make it play nice with the link_to.

Comment: Hi, I am doing this. But I get a little box where my image should be. So it is finding the image, but for some reason won't render it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

Dry one
In your `application_helper.rb`

```
def link_to_image(image_path, target_link,options={})
  link_to(image_tag(image_path, :border => "0"), target_link, options)
end
```

And then from your views

```
<%= link_to_image("path/to/image", some_url) %>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("path/to/image.png"), root_path) %>
```

Where `root_path` is a route for your homepage of your site.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
    <%= image_tag "img.png", height: 27 %>
<% end%>
```

replace root_path and img.png with your path and image name respectively.