# Rails: Image as a link

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image

I want to make a link in my nav bar. The problem is that I want an image as the clickable link. So (click on image -> next Site) 
this is the code I use now for linking with the site.

```
<a class="nav" <%= link_to "Home", posts_path %> </a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn an image into a link in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386318/how-do-i-turn-an-image-into-a-link-in-rails)

Answer (score 8):

You can provide a block to `link_to`

```
<%= link_to posts_path do %>
   <%= image_tag "image" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so the image tag would be something like " url('../assets/example.jpg') " ?

Comment: You can either specify a URL as string or provide the name of an image in your assets. [Just check the docs.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

Comment: now i got this `<%= link_to  posts_path do %>
           <%=  image_tag("logo.gif") %>
              <% end %>`    the logo is there but i cant click it

Comment: @maxbröker Have you checked the DOM/HTML returned from the server? It should definitely be a link (given that you didn’t mess with `posts_path`).

Comment: what do you mean with DOM/HTML? i actually get a link next to the logo (its white space near the logo i can click.) but when i try to click the logo it only shows the magnifying glass .

Comment: @maxbröker Your browser surely has a function to show the source of the page, e.g. a developer console.

Comment: ah, okay. The html line with the image should be okay or ? `<a href="/posts"><img height="32" width="32" src="/assets/logo-b77... .gif" alt="Logo" /></a>`

Comment: @maxbröker That looks fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, but I checked firefox too. the thing is, when I just leave the `<%= link_to posts_path do %> `.  I still got an empty field wich is clickable and link me to the next site .

Comment: okay, i got the image as a link now but when i hover over it it still shows me a magnifying glass. any clue why ?

Comment: @maxbröker No idea. I don’t think neither Chrome nor Firefox show magnifying glasses for normal image tags. Are you using any Javascript that might cause that? Have you probably set the doctype?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=link_to(image_tag("the_best_image_path.jpg", class: "img_class_goes_here"), posts_path, class: "navbar-brand"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Active Storage** on **Rails**, you could do this:

Say, you have a model named `Product` and an attributed named `image`:

**For the Index page**

```
<%= link_to product do %>
  <%= image_tag(product.image, class: 'product-image__img') if product.image.attached? %>
<% end %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to(product) do %>
  <%= image_tag(product.image, class: 'product-image__img') if product.image.attached? %>
<% end %>
```

**For the Show page**

```
<%= image_tag(@product.image, class: 'product-image__img') if @product.image.attached? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="float:none">
    <%= image_tag "yourlogo.png", width:150 %> 
</a>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.