# Can not load image when have an image tag in source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails and here is my problems. I am following railstutorial's book and here is my source code

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

I want to load a photo which name `rails.png`, but it does not load as I expected.
Could you please give me some ideas?
Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Do you have an error ? What is the behavior you are experiencing ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the rails.png image stored in "app/assets/images/rails.png"

Please search more online before asking question

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

[Ruby on Rails displaying image with image_tag src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205085/ruby-on-rails-displaying-image-with-image-tag-src][1])

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I can display my picture in my page now, using your document. Here is my code `<%= image_tag "rails.png"%>`
But I still have a question, why they gave me "link_to" in my source code if there is no need?

Comment: The code you put ```<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>```is correct. It create an image that is a link that will redirect to http://rubyonrails.org/. If you don't want your image to be a link just use the image tag on its own. Otherwise use the link_to. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386318/how-do-i-turn-an-image-into-a-link-in-rails